# Dynamic vs Inline RegExp performance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I stumbled upon that performance test, saying that RegExps in JavaScript are not necessarily slow: http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf

There's one thing i didn't get though: two cases involve something that i believed to be exactly the same:

```
RegExp('(?:^| )foo(?: |$)').test(node.className);
```

And

```
/(?:^| )foo(?: |$)/.test(node.className);
```

In my mind, those two lines were **exactly** the same, the second one being some kind of shorthand to create a RegExp object. Still, it's **twice faster** than the first.

Those cases are called "dynamic regexp" and "inline regexp".

Could someone help me understand the difference (and the performance gap) between these two?

Comment: It's good that the "inline" version is faster, since it's much less ugly than using the explicit constructor anyway.

Comment: For one, you may have overwritten `RegExp` so it a) has to look up the function instead of evaluating it directly, and b) the second one can be evaluated at parse time whereas the first cannot because calling `RegExp` can have side effects in case you've overwritten it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Nowadays, answers given here are not entirely complete/correct.

Starting from ES5, the literal syntax behavior is the same as `RegExp()` syntax regarding object creation: **both of them creates a new RegExp object every time** code path hits an expression in which they are taking part.

Therefore, **the only difference between them now is how often that regexp is compiled**:

- With literal syntax - **one time** during initial code parsing and
  compiling
- With `RegExp()` syntax - **every time** new object gets created

See, for instance, [Stoyan Stefanov's JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) book:

> Another distinction between the regular expression literal and the
>   constructor is that the literal creates an object only once during
>   parse time. If you create the same regular expression in a loop, the
>   previously created object will be returned with all its properties
>   (such as lastIndex) already set from the first time. Consider the
>   following example as an illustration of how the same object is
>   returned twice.

```
function getRE() {
    var re = /[a-z]/;
    re.foo = "bar";
    return re;
}

var reg = getRE(),
    re2 = getRE();

console.log(reg === re2); // true
reg.foo = "baz";
console.log(re2.foo); // "baz"
```

> **This behavior has changed in ES5 and the literal also creates new objects. The behavior has also been corrected in many browser
>   environments, so it’s not to be relied on.**

If you run this sample in all modern browsers or NodeJS, you get the following instead:

```
false
bar
```

Meaning that e**very time you're calling the `getRE()` function, a new `RegExp` object is created even with literal syntax approach**.

The above not only explains why you shouldn't use the `RegExp()` for immutable regexps (it's very well known performance issue today), but also explains:

> (I am more surprised that inlineRegExp and storedRegExp have different
>   results.)

The `storedRegExp` is about 5 - 20% percent faster across browsers than `inlineRegExp` because there is no overhead of creating (and garbage collecting) a new `RegExp` object every time.

**Conclusion:**
Always create your immutable regexps with literal syntax and cache it if it's to be re-used. In other words, don't rely on that difference in behavior in envs below ES5, and continue caching appropriately in envs above.

Why literal syntax? It has some advantages comparing to constructor syntax:

> 1. It is shorter and doesn’t force you to think in terms of class-like
>      constructors.
> 2. When using the `RegExp()` constructor, you also need to escape quotes and double-escape backslashes. It makes regular expressions
>      that are hard to read and understand by their nature even more harder.

(Free citation from the same [Stoyan Stefanov's JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) book).
Hence, it's always a good idea to stick with the literal syntax, unless your regexp isn't known at the compile time.

Comment: Thanks for this nice update! I also like the conclusion, although I'd be tempted to say "go with whatever you prefer to create a regex, literal or constructor, and cache it if it's to be re-used". In other words, don't rely on that difference in behavior in envs below ES5, and continue caching appropriately in envs above :)

Comment: @Pioul, thank you for the feedback! I've updated my answer and added as you suggested except the part about constructor pattern. See my answer why :)

Comment: @Pioul, though I've removed the outdated parts from my answer, I feel this should be the expected answer. So, can you please accept this one? That will remove the checkmark from my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Arjan, thank you! This is truly respectable act of yours!

Comment: Well, fun fact: see [the last comment at dldnh's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750338/dynamic-vs-inline-regexp-performance-in-javascript#comment18031984_9750369) ;-) Fun aside, the best answer should be the accepted one!

Comment: Done! Props for keeping things up to date, even 6 years later!

Answer (score 12):

The difference in performance <s>is not related to the syntax that is used</s> is partly related to the syntax that is used: in `/pattern/` and `RegExp(/pattern/)` (where you did not test the latter) the regular expression is only compiled once, but for `RegExp('pattern')` the expression is compiled on each usage. See [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750338/dynamic-vs-inline-regexp-performance-in-javascript/32523333#32523333), which should be the accepted answer today.

Apart from the above, in your tests for `inlineRegExp` and `storedRegExp` you're looking at code that is initialized once when the source code text is parsed, while for `dynamicRegExp` the regular expression is created for each invocation of the method. Note that the [actual tests](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf) run things like `r = dynamicRegExp(element)` many times, while the preparation code is only run once.

The following gives you about the same results, [according to another jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf/24):

```
var reContains = /(?:^| )foo(?: |$)/;
```

...and

```
var reContains = RegExp('(?:^| )foo(?: |$)');
```

...when both are used with

```
function storedRegExp(node) {
  return reContains.test(node.className);
}
```

Sure, the source code of `RegExp('(?:^| )foo(?: |$)')` might first be parsed into a `String`, and then into a `RegExp`, but I doubt that by itself will be twice as slow. However, the following will create a new `RegExp(..)` *again and again* for each method call:

```
function dynamicRegExp(node) {
  return RegExp('(?:^| )foo(?: |$)').test(node.className);
}
```

If in the original test you'd only call each method once, then the inline version would not be a whopping 2 times faster.

(I am more surprised that `inlineRegExp` and `storedRegExp` have different results. This is explained in [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750338/dynamic-vs-inline-regexp-performance-in-javascript/32523333#32523333) too.)

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense, thank you. You might want to highlight [your jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf/24) since it helped me understand where the difference in performance comes from (between `dynamicStoredRegExp` and `dynamicRegExp`). And about your last statement, it's not that much of a difference, I'd dismiss that.

Comment: As for that the difference between `inlineRegExp` and `storedRegExp`: the first [is half as fast in the latest Safari 6.0](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf/24)...‽

Comment: Didn't see that, on Safari 6.0 both `storedRegExp` and `dynamicStoredRegExp` are about twice as fast as `inlineRegExp`, when on other browsers it's pretty much the same. Now I'm also curious about what might be happening here with Safari...

Comment: So an inlineRegExp `/pattern yada yada/` is effectively a regex *constant* and is only ever compiled once, while `RegExp()` is an actual function call that's executed every time. Is that right?

Comment: @Edward, almost. Both `/pattern/` and `RegExp('pattern')` will create a new Object, like you can read in Alexander's answer. But using a literal like `/pattern/` rather than a string ensures the regular expression itself only needs to be compiled once. So, nowadays `/pattern/` and `RegExp(/pattern/)` will actually be the same, but for `RegExp('pattern')` the regular expression itself is compiled each time.

Comment: Got it. But the bottom line is that I don't have to feel bad for using .e.g. `if (/foo/.test(string)) { … }` in a loop.

Comment: @Edward in a loop that would still create a new Object each time. But it would not have to compile the regular expression for each new Object. But readable code wins :-)

Comment: OK, so I *should* avoid using the /…/ form inside a loop. Instead, create a variable outside the loop and use that.

Answer (score 6):

in the second case, the regular expression object is created during the parsing of the language, and in the first case, the RegExp class constructor has to parse an arbitrary string.

Comment: What you're saying is that in the first case, the regexp kind of goes through a "string" state before being "understood" by the engine?

Comment: oh, even better, tell me if i'm right: slashes work as regex delimiters, so that a slash implies a regex as much as a quote implies a string?