# Text find and replace chrome extensions - how do they work so fast?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In my chrome extension, I am trying to get every text element on the page, check what it is, and replace it if it is that thing. Here is my first approach:

```
function textNodesUnder(el){
    var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
    return a;
}

const nodes = textNodesUnder(document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]);

    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        // replace text
        for (let k in whatToReplace) {
            nodes[i].nodeValue = nodes[i].nodeValue.replace(new RegExp(k, "gi"), whatToReplace[k])
        }
```

Works, but very, very slow - 5-10 seconds to process a page. I am more of a server side/Golang developer, so I realize I may be barking up the wrong tree here, but - how do most text find and replace style chrome extensions work so quickly? Is this where something like a Webworker would come in handy?

Comment: Diabetus! I'd remove the unused previous attempts from the question to keep it concise. Glad to hear you're making progress. Are you able to just apply the regex on everything all at once instead of running any loops? can you log some timestamps to verify where the lag is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big bottle-neck is probably that you are compiling the regular expression every iteration inside of that inner loop. Compiling a regular expression doesn't take too long, but when you are doing it for every node you are crawling multiplied by the number of replacement pairs you have, it adds up.

You appear to be storing the replacement information as an object, thus necessitating converting from a string to regular expression using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```
const whatToReplace = {
  ipsum: 'IPSUM',
  'Vivamus|vehicula': 'VROOM!',
  '^Donec': 'donut',
  'eros': 'lust',
  'semper': 'always'
};
```

Instead, I would store them as an array of arrays containing a `RegExp` literal and it's replacement text.

```
const whatToReplace = [
  [/ipsum/gi, 'IPSUM'],
  [/Vivamus|vehicula/, 'VROOM!'],
  [/^Donec/, 'donut'],
  [/eros/, 'lust'],
  [/semper/, 'always']
];
```

Then you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of `for...in` to iterate over it:

```
const whatToReplace = [
  [/ipsum/gi, 'IPSUM'],
  [/Vivamus|vehicula/gi, 'VROOM!'],
  [/^Donec/gi, 'donut'],
  [/eros/gi, 'lust'],
  [/semper/gi, 'always']
];

const contentNode = document.querySelector(".content");

let walk = document.createTreeWalker(contentNode,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
let node;
while((node = walk.nextNode())) {
  // replace text
  for (let [rx, replacement] of whatToReplace) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(rx, replacement);
  }
}
```

This code also saves a little time and memory by just altering each node as it walks the tree instead of storing it in a array and then looping over it. Since we are just looking for the first element with the `.content` class, I used [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `getElementsByClassName` as it only looks for one element instead of all the elements with that class, so it should be faster too.

If you can't store them as literals, for instance if you are getting them from user input, you can still compile them beforehand one time outside the loop:

```
let whatToReplace = {
  ipsum: 'IPSUM',
  'Vivamus|vehicula': 'VROOM!',
  '^Donec': 'donut',
  'eros': 'lust',
  'semper': 'always'
};

// convert whatToReplace into an array like the one in the previous example
whatToReplace = Object.entries(whatToReplace).reduce(function (acc, [key, value]) {
  acc.push([new RegExp(key, 'gi'), value])
  return acc;
}, []);

const contentNode = document.querySelector(".content");

let walk = document.createTreeWalker(contentNode,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
let node;
while((node = walk.nextNode())) {
  // replace text
  for (let [rx, replacement] of whatToReplace) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(rx, replacement);
  }
}
```

Another bottle-neck could be the fact that you are altering the DOM a lot. Every time you alter a node you could be causing a repaint and/or a reflow. That can kill performance in the browser. You can fix this by first removing the part of the DOM tree you are going to be altering, alter it while it is not in the DOM and then reinsert it into the DOM:

```
const whatToReplace = [
  [/ipsum/gi, 'IPSUM'],
  [/Vivamus|vehicula/gi, 'VROOM!'],
  [/^Donec/gi, 'donut'],
  [/eros/gi, 'lust'],
  [/semper/gi, 'always']
];

const contentNode = document.querySelector(".content");
const parent = contentNode.parentNode;
const placeholder = document.createElement('div');

// remove it from the DOM and replace it with a placeholder
parent.replaceChild(placeholder, contentNode);

let walk = document.createTreeWalker(contentNode,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
let node;
while((node = walk.nextNode())) {
  // replace text
  for (let [rx, replacement] of whatToReplace) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(rx, replacement);
  }
}

// swap our altered element back into the DOM
parent.replaceChild(contentNode, placeholder);
```

According to the [performance test](https://jsperf.com/regexp-stored-as-string-vs-stored-as-regexp-literal) I created, in Chrome removing it from the DOM first doesn't seem to make a huge difference, but it does make it a little faster. If you have to deal with Firefox it does make a big difference. Interestingly, removing it from the DOM appears to make a 5% difference in Edge, but using strings on an object instead of an array of RegExp literals appears to be faster for some reason.

**Further reading**

- [Dynamic vs Inline RegExp performance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750338/dynamic-vs-inline-regexp-performance-in-javascript#32523333)
- [Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)
- [The DOM isn’t slow, you are.](https://korynunn.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/the-dom-isnt-slow-you-are/)
- [`Object.entries` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Well, this was about as good an answer as anybody could hope to get on StackOverflow. You've sped up my chrome extension to running at around 400 milliseconds with a fairly large (150) array of arrays. Thank you very much for the comprehensive reply. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend:

1. Don't collect all the text nodes into a single array. This may lead to one huge array.
2. The regexp objects can be reused by some buffering skills. This might help reduce the processing time.
3. You can skip some text nodes to save performing time. For example, skip the text nodes that contain empty/all-spaces text.
4. The node array is not necessary. The text nodes can be performed one at a time recursively through treeWalker.